# Mascarar colunas especificas do banco Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho uma tabela no banco onde quero trocar os dados de algumas colunas dela para 'xxx' para usuários que não sejam administradores quando eles fizerem o select.

```
select name, cpf from student
```

retornar as colunas normais para usuários administradores e retornar 'xxx' para os que não são, sem usar views

Sei que fazer isso pelo sql server é relativamente simples, mas não encontrei maneiras de fazer pelo postgres

tentei usando o seguinte código e nenhum gerou resultado.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION censurar_nome_func(student)
RETURNS student AS $$
DECLARE
    masked_data student;
BEGIN
    IF current_user <> 'adm' THEN
        masked_data.name := 'XXXXX';
        masked_data.cpf := 'XXXXX';
        RETURN masked_data;
    ELSE
        RETURN masked_data;
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE POLICY censurar_nome_func ON student
    FOR SELECT
    USING (true)
    WITH CHECK (true)
    USING (censurar_nome_func(student.*));
```

Retornando o erro, função tem que retornar um booleano

tentei usar o postgresql_anonymizer14 também, mas não consegui instalar em ambiente windowsp

Comment: Ola ! Que erro é apresentado?

Comment: ele gera o erro que a função tem que retornar um booleano

Comment: É necessário acrescentar os erros de saída às suas perguntas

Comment: "fazer isso pelo sql server é relativamente simples" , como ?! Pelo que vi o PG permite grant em nível de coluna , uma solucão seria só liberar estas colunas em certo nível. Colunas virtuais tratariam a máscara ....  https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/data/9781789537581/6/ch06lvl1sec78/granting-user-access-to-specific-columns .... https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html .... pergunta interessante face a LGPD.

Comment: @Motta ALTER TABLE student ALTER COLUMN Name ADD MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()'); dessa forma, obrigado pelos links mas não me ajudram

Comment: Não conhecia isto , útil para LGPD.

Comment: Esta pergunta é útil , relevante , pode ser reproduzida , qual a razão da negativação ?!

Comment: só quem deu o negativo sabe. @Motta